# How to generate Spotify song preview in Facebook messenger using Dialogflow chat-bot

Tags: facebook-messenger, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to make a chat bot based on facebook's Messenger, I knew that now if you send a spotify song url in facebook's messenger, it will render a playable clip. However I don't know how to achieve this through facebook's api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you would send an open graph template:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/open-graph